# need to print the column names of results from a query automatically

Tags: html, sql, asp-classic

```
strUserQuery = request.querystring("UserQuery")
strQueryToBeExecuted = "Select * from (" & strUserQuery & ") where rownum < 501"
```

How do I print the headings for the table automatically when the query runs? I tried printing off the first line but the query result does not have column names in it.

I also tried using desc (table name), but that didn't work either. 
I'd be very thankful if someone could guide me.

Comment: do you want to print the column names of the table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you putting the data into a recordset? If so, try:

```
For Each field in recordset.fields
Response.write field.name & "<br />"
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you pulling it into excel or just having a query.If you just having a query it shows up automatically. Or if you are doing it on code we just need data not the column names as it automatically takes it.